# cmake: build depends on none-source files. Qt help generation

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to generate Qt help files during build.

`.qhp` (Qt help project), contains list of HTML files located in `/html` folder adjacent to `.qhp` file.

It works fine, if I change `.qhp` file. But if I change only HTML files the build is not started.

This is part of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_custom_command( 
    OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/help.qch 
    COMMAND qhelpgenerator ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/help.qhp -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/help.qch
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/help.qhp
)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET_NAME} 
    ALL DEPENDS 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/help.qch
    SOURCES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/uav_help.qhp
)
```

Q: How can I add dependencies to HTML files (w/o creating list of them in `CMakeLists.txt`), if I don't want to add them to the project?

Q2: Are there other ways to organize automatic `.qch` generation during build?

Answer (score 0):

List these HTML's in `DEPENDS` of `add_custom_command()` call too, obviously.

You can also look at KDE's Extra CMake Modules project, which contains [ECMAddQch](https://api.kde.org/ecm/module/ECMAddQch.html) macro.